# Making walls in OpenGL

Tags: eclipse, jogl

How do I make walls in JOGL 2.0 in Eclipse?
So far, I've tried it with listing vertices, until I realised that was a C method while I need to work it in java.

Comment: OK so if it's a C method, then how exactly have you tried it in JOGL 2.0 and Eclipse? Sounds like all you've tried is writing code that won't compile because it's not Java code.

Answer (score 0):

There are OpenGL bindings for Java, a good one is LWJGL. And yes, the methods are like C but adapted to Java so you'll be good with that. To make a wall, you can list some vertices, put them in a vertex buffer object and with an element buffer object specify the order in which they must appear. http://open.gl is a good learning resource for modern OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

If you have plenty of patience and time, you should go for a deep opengl tutorial like ["Learning Modern 3D Graphic Programming"](http://web.archive.org/web/20140209181347/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) of Jason L. McKesson (aka Nicol Bolas). I ported his C samples to Jogl [here](https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples). Another one very good is [ogldev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/), from Etay Meiri, which I am still porting [here](https://github.com/elect86/oglDevTutorials).

If you need it *quick & dirty*, take a look to my [jogl-samples](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples). There you will find an Hello Triangle, an Hello Texture and tens of small tests regarding OpenGL calls and techniques.

Forgive my links, it is my ego ^^.

**Avoid** any [deprecated stuff](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL#Detecting_legacy_OpenGL) at your life cost, target OpenGL 3.3+.
You won't regret, more info [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140207031129/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/About%20this%20Book.html#d0e30).

If you need any further help, just ask.